# Creating a SQL view checking for various conditions fed from another table

Tags: sql-server, validation

I would like to create a view called Errors that is fed from another Settings table which contains the conditions.

The settings table would have 2 columns like this:

```
+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|      Description       |                     Criteria                     |
+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Missing birth country  |  from stu where bcu = ''                         |
| Email invalid          |  from con where em not like '%@%.%' and em <> '' |
+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

The errors view would look just be a two columns like this (note ID is a student ID for illustration purposes can just be any number)

```
+------+------------------------+
|  ID  |          Error         |
+------+------------------------+
| 123  |  Email invalid         |
| 123  |  Missing birth country |
| 234  |  Email invalid         |
+------+------------------------+
etc...
```

This is what I have for SQL View so far. How can I create a dynamic view to pull these settings from a settings table?

```
--missing birth country
select id,
'Missing birth country.' as err
from stu where bcu = '' and del = 0

union all

--invalid email format
select id,
'Email invalid format in Contacts' as err
from con where em not like '%@%.%' and em <> '' and del = 0
```

Note this is with MS SQL Server, and I would prefer a solution that works with 2008+ but open to various options too.

Comment: Does the `settings` table has only those two columns?

Comment: That's a nice idea!

Comment: @Sami In my example above the settings table has only 2 columns, however it likely will eventually have additional fields to set various parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)

SET @SQL = N''

SELECT
    @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT id, '''+ Description + ''' as err ' + Criteria +CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'UNION ALL'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
FROM settings

SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 11)
PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

You should probably improve it by escaping characters in Description strings, but this is the core answer to your question.

---

Edit: using OP comment to create table function and view that calls it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tvf_getErrors
   RETURNS  TABLE  AS

    (
     SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost; Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'EXEC(N''sp_executesql N'''''' + ''SELECT ''''''''select '''''''' + pk + '''''''' as id, '''''''''''''''''''''''' + de + '''''''''''''''''''''''' as err '''''''' + CR + '''''''' UNION ALL'''''''' as sql FROM DVAS'''''' )')
    )
RETURN
GO
```

I simply can't check if all ' are there... And looks even uglier. Now, all you have to do is to reference this table valued function inside view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.v_getErrors 
AS 
SELECT * FROM dbo.tvf_getErrors()
```

While doing this, I realized you could ommit using table valued function and call OpenRowSet directly from view, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.v_getErrors 
AS 
     SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost; Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'EXEC(N''sp_executesql N'''''' + ''SELECT ''''''''select '''''''' + pk + '''''''' as id, '''''''''''''''''''''''' + de + '''''''''''''''''''''''' as err '''''''' + CR + '''''''' UNION ALL'''''''' as sql FROM DVAS'''''' )')
```

There it is. Once you figure out all the apostrophes this will work.

Comment: This almost works, except getting conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int. I think something is wrong around the LEFT function but I'm not sure what. I can tell the SQL is getting generated correctly, but the last UNION ALL is not getting trimmed off. Or maybe it's the escaping that I need.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It was an error - I've edited it - try it now.

Comment: Ok now this works perfectly, except that when I create a view. I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'. I learned you cannot declare variables in a View....are there alternates?

Comment: Sorry, no to my knowledge. I don't know any way to include custom text as a part of query except to create dynamic SQL and then execute it.
This can be inside Stored Procedure and running that SP will return data set which can then be accessed both from various languages and T-SQL itself.
And by the way, this is 2008+ compliant.

Comment: I have this so far...it's close I think, but it looks ugly: EXEC(N'sp_executesql N''' + 'SELECT ''''select '''' + pk + '''' as id, '''''''''''' + de + '''''''''''' as err '''' + CR + '''' UNION ALL'''' as sql FROM DVAS''' )

Comment: It's a one-liner of what I wrote and it is ugly, you are right. And that can be transformed into table function, which in return can be called from view. I'll edit my answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: I like what you did here, however, I don't think I can depend on enabling anything on the server like ad hoc distributed queries or advanced. Should I do it a different way?

Comment: If you are ok with calling stored procedure prior to calling view - you could store results in some form of temporary table.

Comment: I need the end result to be a view. My application I am working with can only see views and tables.

Answer (score 3):

Create a stored procedure like this (I got help from @The_Player's code):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testPrc]
AS
set nocount on
SET FMTONLY OFF
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)

SET @SQL = N''

SELECT
@SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT id, '''+ Description + ''' as err ' + Criteria         +CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'UNION ALL'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
FROM settings

SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 11)
PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

END
```

Run this commands:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Create thie view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[testView]
AS
SELECT        ID, err
FROM            OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
'exec TestDB.dbo.testPrc WITH RESULT SETS (  (    ID INT,   err VARCHAR(150)   )  ) 
') AS derivedtbl_1
GO
```

---

Edited :
The second solution without stored procedure:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[testView2]
AS
SELECT ID, err
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
'EXECUTE sp_executesql   
N''SELECT
@SQL = @SQL + ''''SELECT id, ''''+''''''''''''''''+ Description +     ''''''''''''''''+'''' as err '''' + Criteria +CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+''''UNION     ALL''''+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
FROM TestDB.dbo.settings
SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 11)
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
WITH RESULT SETS (  (    ID INT,   err VARCHAR(150)   )  ) 
'',  
N''@SQL NVARCHAR(max)'',  
@SQL = N'''' 
WITH RESULT SETS (  (    ID INT,   err VARCHAR(150)   )  )' ) AS     derivedtbl_1
GO
```

Just a few points
You should add database name and schema name at the first of the table name.
For example:

```
from stu where bcu = ''
```

should be :

```
from TestDB.dbo.stu where bcu = ''
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but looks neat. Is there a way to do this with just a view and a table? I'd prefer not to create a stored procedure since that would be three objects in the DB I would have to maintain versus two.

Comment: I don't think I can depend on enabling anything on the server. ad hoc distributed queries or advanced. Any other way? Should I do it a different way?